# How to remove <div class="menu"> from Walker_Nav_Menu of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove `<div class="menu">` from Walker_Nav_Menu ,I am getting default `<div class='menu'>` in menues ,I have tried to rename container in but it is not working

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-66"><a href="http://localhost/wp/about-us/">About Us</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-72"><a href="http://localhost/wp/contact-us/">Contact us</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-70 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/wp/enquiry/">Enquiry</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-74"><a href="http://localhost/wp/home/">Home</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-68"><a href="http://localhost/wp/product/">Product</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wp/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**code to print menu**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>

$defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container1' => '', 'container_class' => 'false', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => '', 'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '' );
```

Comment: `'menu_class' => ''` is one of the arguments you can pass which will remove the menu class?

Comment: Also give the code from which you are getting that menu.

Comment: I have mentioned code to print menu

Comment: Still div is not getting removed , i have changed 'menu_class' => ''  but div remain as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to add is `false` in `container` argument to achieve this.So it will be something like `container=>false`.

**But it will only work** if you have correct `theme_location`. **For an example**, If you are using default menu in wordpress without creating any menu or without assigning any location to created menu, then above suggestion will not work.

So **to make it work**, create menu and assign location to it and make sure your `wp_nav_menu` also contains same location.

**Edited**

Replace your theme's `header.php` Line 21 with following code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container'=>false, 'menu_class'=> 'your_class_name' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: I have tested it ! You might be missing something ..Try some debugging please :)

Comment: @abhiAhere Are you kidding me ? `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container'=>false ) ); ?>` This code is working perfectly fine. You must not added your menu to `main-menu` location.

Comment: ok,it was my fault,but if i want to add class to first ul ,how it can be done?

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot too! I know it's slightly off topic but is there away to add classes onto the list-items and anchors using the `wp_nav_menu` array? Total novice here!

Comment: @user1406440 Yes.It is possible. You can create your own class extending wordpress menu class. [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the container argument to declare if you want to use a div or ul.

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'container' => 'ul'
);

echo wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Comment: where should i ,make this change ,in  waker_nav_menu ?

Comment: You should replace the code you use to output your menu, with the code provided (Remember to add <?php before and ?> after it)

Comment: same problem , div before <ul>  not getting removed

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching systems, e.g. WP Super Cache? If so you may need to purge the cache.

Comment: not using any  caching systems ,only making changes in nav-menu-template.php ,

Comment: So you are editing the core file inside of wp-includes?

Comment: Core files should not be edited, instead you should use filters and actions to edit the output before it reaches the page. If you would like to still edit the core file do this change: Line 227 (Starts with $defaults) and change 'container' => 'div' to 'container' => 'ul'

Comment: <div class="menu"> is still not getting removed ,from where should,div can be removed

Comment: If you go to your theme functions.php file (wp-themes/{your current theme}/functions.php) and add this code:


add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', function($args) {
 $args['container'] = 'ul';
 return $args;
});

Comment: I am using blankslate theme is that making any difference

Comment: It shouldn't but they may be overriding the container argument, so the change in my last comment should fix that

Comment: In function.php there is a line add_filter( 'the_title', 'blankslate_title' ); should i edit it ?

Comment: *Update*: I have had a look at the blankslate theme, if you open wp-contents/themes/blankslate/header.php, change `array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' )` to `array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container' => 'ul' )`

Comment: I have made changes,  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container' => 'ul' ) ); but not working ,

Comment: @JamieSimmonds It will not remove `<div>`. Your code will add `ul` instead of removing.

Comment: Could you try `array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container' => false )` *Update*: I see you got your answer already :)